# nativescript-dev-webpack before-prepareJSApp hook not called

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript

I'm trying to use webpack to bundle my Nativescript app, but I'm having some issues.

First issue is running the following command:

```
 tns build android --bundle
```

When I do that, I'm fairly certain nothing is happening in terms of webpack. I see this output:

```
 Executing before-prepare hook from F:\workspace\myproject\hooks\before-
 prepare\nativescript-dev-sass.js
 Executing before-prepare hook from F:\workspace\myproject\hooks\before-
 prepare\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
 Preparing project...
 Project successfully prepared (android)
 Executing after-prepare hook from F:\workspace\myproject\hooks\after-
 prepare\nativescript-dev-sass.js
 All SASS source files removed from app package
 Executing after-prepare hook from F:\workspace\myproject\hooks\after-
 prepare\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
 Executing after-prepare hook from F:\workspace\myproject\hooks\after-
 prepare\nativescript-unit-test-runner.js
 Building project...
 Gradle build...
```

No errors, but the nativescript-dev-webpack before-prepare hook is not called. I have a before-prepareJSApp folder with nativescript-dev-webpack.js file in my project, but for some reason it's not being invoked.

Another issue, possibly related is when I attempt to run this:

```
  tns build android --bundle --env.aot --env.uglify --env.snapshot
```

The output of that is simply:

```
 The option 'env' is not supported. To see command's options, use '$ tns help build'. To see all commands use '$ tns help'.
```

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user1513171 you are probably using an older version of `NativeScript CLI` and/or `nativescript-dev-webpack` as the flags like `--env.aot` were introduced in the latest versions.

Update NativeScript CLI to latest (at this very moment 3.4.x or above) and nativescript-dev-webpack to the latest official version (at this very moment 0.9.1)

Full guide on how to migrate to the latest Wwbpack can be found [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-webpack-0.9.0-what-changed-and-how-to-upgrade)